# How to query Facebook PHP Business SDK for Adsets with updated_time in the past two weeks?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the [Facebook PHP Business SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk) to retrieve adsets that have an updated_time value in the past two weeks.

So far I have:

```
$adsets = $campaign->getAdsets(
    [AdSetFields::NAME, AdSetFields::UPDATED_TIME], // fields
    [AdSetFields::UPDATED_TIME => AdSetDatePresetValues::LAST_14D] // params
);
```

The params part does not seem to have an effect on the data being returned. Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution:

The params parameter has to be in the following format:

```
    $currentDateTimeObj = new DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
    $fourteenDaysAgoDateTimeObj = $currentDateTimeObj->sub(new DateInterval('P14D'));

    $inactiveUpdatedCampaignsParams = [
        'filtering' => [
            ['field' =>  CampaignFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS, 'operator' => 'NOT_IN',  'value' => ['ACTIVE']],
            ['field' => 'adset.updated_time', 'operator' => 'GREATER_THAN',  'value' => $fourteenDaysAgoDateTimeObj->getTimestamp()]
        ]
    ];
```

In the above example, when making the following Facebook API call `$adAccount->getCampaigns($fields, $inactiveFutureCampaignsParams);` it will return Campaigns that do not have a 'ACTIVE' effective status and has adsets that have an updated_time in the last two weeks.

Its a shame this isn't documented in the Facebook PHP Business SDK documentation.